# speed up bash script by starting several instances in a for loop

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, inkscape

I have this script:

```
 for i in `find ! -newermt "2016-02-13" -name "*svgz"`; do
  inkscape --verb FitCanvasToDrawing --verb FileSave --verb FileClose ${i} --verb FileQuit
done
```

which waits for inkscape to finish its job and then restarts it with the next file. I would like to have four instances of inkscape run in parallel to speed up the process (I have ~ 5,000 files to process). Is that possible, and if yes, how?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try GNU Parallel.

```
sudo aptitude install parallel
```

I haven't used it in a while but its command line should be similar to the one below:

```
find ! -newermt "2016-02-13" -name "*svgz" | \
  parallel -j4 \
    inkscape \
    --verb FitCanvasToDrawing \
    --verb FileSave \
    --verb FileClose {} \
    --verb FileQuit
```

where 4 is the number of processes that you want to run at any given time.

Comment: Thanks very much, this one sounds nice and easy enough for a noob like me... ;-)

Comment: You're welcome :) Everyone starts somewhere - good luck!

Comment: Well, I tried your solution, but now after each starting inkscape, inkscape did  not close, but stayed open with an empty file. I then found that the \ lacked after the {}. I inserted it, and now it works perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, good catch, I must have overlooked it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use GNU parallel, as explained here for a very similar question also involving inkscape:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572397/how-to-process-20k-svg-files-with-inkscape-cli-mode-align-and-merge-objects

Another simple trick I used myself recently is as follows:

1. Create a shellscript "process.sh" processing a single file passed as
   argument to it.
2. Store the result of the find command in a text file
3. Split the file using the "split" command into as many jobs as you want
   to run in parallel.
4. Run multiple instances of process.sh passing
   arguments to it via the generated split files and xargs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would approach this. Since I do not have same files, the example code bellow aims to open 4 text files with `gedit`.

How does this work ? Well, first we find the files in the hard-coded location where the files may be stored ( `FILEPATH` variable ). Then we pass it on to `while read` structure. Note the use of `-print0` and `IFS= read -d''`. This is very common in bash programming to eliminate  problematic filenames that contain spaces, unprintable characters, etc.

Each `gedit file &` calls `gedit` being detatched from the script with `&`. That makes while loop go on without stopping.

What does make the loop stop is the COUNT variable. Once we count from 0 to some number divisible by 4, the `MOD` variable , which is calculated from modulus operator, will become 0. Now the shell will wait for a popup ( which is `zenity` ) to confirm spawning 4 more windows . That way we count 4 times, reset variable, continue.

The only disadvantage here is that `find` does not sort the files, so they won't necessarily be in the named order. If order matters, the code will need additional instructions. Otherwise, this is sufficient.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

FILEPATH="/home/xieerqi/MYTEXTFILES"
COUNT=0

find $FILEPATH -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | \
while IFS= read -d ''  FILE;
do
    gedit $FILE & 
    COUNT=$(( $COUNT+1 ))
    MOD=$(( $COUNT % 4 ))

    if [ $MOD -eq 0   ]
    then 
        zenity --question --text "Open 4 more files?"  || exit
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice script. It doesn't help in my case though, as I have about 2,000 files to open and edit (which would still make for about 500 times answering the zenity popup...) ;-)
Is there a "wait" command I could use, so that it would wait for say 10 seconds before the next loop? Maybe that would suffice...

Comment: In that case `sleep 10` is the command you need